# AVAudioSequencer playing AVAudioUnitSampler cuts of tail end of midi notes

Tags: ios, avfoundation, musicsequence

I am playing a midi file using AVAudioSequencer and AVAudioUnitSampler.   A midi file is being loaded into a MusicSequence object.  The notes are being cut off as soon as another note is played essentially making it monophonic.

For example, a crash cymbal on beat 1 should sustain across the measure.  However, the crash is cut off as soon as another note plays.

Can this be fixed so that notes will not be cut off?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the that the AUPreset file was not configured properly and the notes were not sustaining.